# Using Android WorkManager in Nativescript

Tags: nativescript

I'm building a Nativescript-Angular (Android and iOS) app that should guarantee uploading zip files to a server. App should check for new zip files every 4 hours. Uploading can be deferred.

I understand that the best way to the above job in Android is to use the WorkManager, because the job execution is guaranteed, and the work can be deferred (doesn't have to happen now, but it will surely happen in the future).

How can I use Android WorkManager in Nativescript?

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/using-android-background-services-in-nativescript) to create an android service using nativescript, and the corresponding [nativescript android background service example](https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-android-background-services), but is uses jobScheduler instead.

For the uploading itself I'm currently using [Nativescript Background Http Plugin](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-background-http) that uses [NSURLSession with background session configuration for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessionconfiguration#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLSessionConfiguration/backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:); and [alexbbb/android-upload-service](https://github.com/alexbbb/android-upload-service) - but it's not a good choice because I have to constantly check for new files every 4 hours and upload them to a server.

Any idea on how to implement and use Android WorkManager in Nativescript?

Thanks,

Comment: WorkManager seems to be Android X specific, it may not work on the existing older versions and you might be still left with JobScheduler. NativeScript background http is still a good choice, may be you just have to wrap it within a background service which may run for every 4 hours. You can use background fetch in iOS but you can not really control when it should run, it's decided by the iOS itself.

Comment: Indeed WorkManager is part of Android Jetpack which comprises the androidx.* package libraries, unbundled from the platform APIs. But this means that it does offer backward compatibility and it will work with existing older versions. The question is - Are AndroidX packages supported by Nativescript?

Comment: NativeScript does support AndroidX, you may read more about that at [this blog post](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/support-for-androidx-in-nativescript). But I don't think androidx apis are backward compatible, those are going to work only on AndroidX and not on any earlier versions.